# Finding the index of the first and last 1 in a binary number

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I want to write a function that returns the index of the first and last 1 in a binary number.

for example:

```
binNumber = b'0001101'
first, last = findIndex(binNumber)
print("first index is ",first, " and last index is ", last)
```

**and the output will be:**
first index is 3 and last index is 6

Answer (score 2):

Use the `index` and `rindex` methods.

```
>>> binNumber.index(b'1')
3
>>> binNumber.rindex(b'1')
6
```

Will throw a `ValueError` in case there's no 1.

---

If there's no particular reason your `binNumber` is a `bytes` object, make it a string and use `binNumber.index('1')` and `binNumber.rindex('1')`.

Comment: `ValueError` can be avoided by `find` and `rfind` respectively (returns -1).

Comment: @Austin yes. I prefer getting the error because `-1` is a valid index. `b = '0000000'; b[b.find('1')]` -> `'0'`.

Comment: I'm not sure if OP is planning to index it again - in any case why would he want that?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `find` and `rfind` for this.

```
>>> b'0001101'.find('1')
3
>>> 
>>> 
>>> b'0001101'.rfind('1')
6
```

Your definition would be

```
>>> def findIndex(binNumber):
        return binNumber.find('1'), binNumber.rfind('1')

>>> binNumber = b'0001101'
>>> first, last = findIndex(binNumber)
>>> first
3
>>> last
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Change binNumber as string, and use index.

Try this code.

```
def findIndex(binNumber):
    start = str(binNumber)[2:].index('1')
    end = len(binNumber) - str(binNumber)[2:][::-1].index('1')
    return start, end
```